# how to test window.status variable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara, minitest, capybara-webkit

I'm using wkhtmlpdf library to convert pdf from the HTML page. this page depends on heavy javascript functions (ajax calls, google maps) so that I had to use `--window-status` and `--javascript-delay` options. I'm setting the value `window.status="ready_to_print;"` when everything is done. It's working properly and pdf are rendering as It should be.

Now I want to create a ruby on rails unit/integration test to check that the HTML page has rendered to the correct state. how can I test this using rpec, capybara or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Capybara when you want to get access to the values of JS things you use `evaluate_script`. In this case that would mean

```
evaluate_script('window.status')
```

If you want to wait for that be some value you could wrap it in a loop (possibly with a timeout), or if you just want to verify it is a specific value right now

```
expect(evaluate_script('window.status')).to eq 'ready_to_print'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's an exposed method in the selenium ruby bindings, but the `watir` DSL has a [`Browser::status`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Browser#status-instance_method) method, which is implemented as follows and should do the trick:

```
def status
  execute_script 'return window.status;'
end
```